# Counterexamples to Margulis Normal subgroup theorem in rank 1

Tags: gr.group-theory, lie-groups, algebraic-groups, geometric-group-theory

Margulis' normal subgroup theorem states that any normal subgroup of a higher rank irreducible lattice is either finite or of finite index. 
What are the known counter-examples in rank $1$ ?

I am especially interested by $PU(2,1)$.

Comment: Not an answer, but: the commutator subgroup of $F_2$ is infinite and has infinite index. So I would start looking at something similar inside SL(2,Z) viewed as a lattice inside SL(2,R)

Comment: @YemonChoi: Actually, what you wrote **is** an answer!

Comment: For a hyperbolic manifold of positive first Betti number (e.g., the complement of any hyperbolic link) the commutator subgroup is a normal subgroup of infinite index. I guess it is often (always?) also an infinite group.

Comment: @ThiKu, yes, always. Otherwise the fundamental group of your manifold would be virtually abelian! Of course, we now know that *all* hyperbolic 3-manifolds have a finite-index subgroup with $b_1>0$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any cocompact lattice in a rank-one Lie group is *word-hyperbolic*.  Olshanskii proved that such groups are SQ-universal, meaning in particular that they have uncountably many normal subgroups.  Similar results are known for non-uniform lattices, which are *relatively hyperbolic*.

As Yemon Choi suggests in comments, the simplest example comes from $PSL(2,\mathbb{Z})$. The 2-congruence subgroup $\Gamma(2)$ is free of rank two, and hence surjects every two-generator group.

Comment: Same for nonuniform rank 1 lattices ([Arzhantseva-Minasyan-Osin](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0601590)).

Comment: In "Filling Riemaniann Manifold", Gromov "remarked" that in a compact manifold with strictly negative curvature the normal subgroup of the fundamental group generated by the high power of an element is a free group, hence of infinite index ; SQ universality for hyperbolic groups is stated in his (Gromov's) paper on hyperbolic groups. These statements generated a huge literature, not only in Olshanskii's work..

Comment: $\Gamma_2$ contains $-Id$.

Comment: @few_reps: Sorry, I meant in $PSL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, of course.

Answer (score 2):

Also interesting in this context is the existence of compact complex surfaces whose universal cover is the ball and admitting an holomorphic map onto a Riemann surface with connected fibers. The kernel of the induced map is a finitely generated group of infinite index. This is similar to the existence (Rips counterexample) of finitely generated normal subgroup in certain small cancelation groups with arbitrary complicated f.p. quotient.

Comment: Am I right in thinking that it's open whether or not every lattice in $PU(2,1)$ is large, i.e. virtually surjects a free group?

Comment: @HJRW: Yes, I think that's right. For the arithmetic congruence lattices of "second type", Rogawski showed that the first betti number is always zero. I think it's not known whether one of these lattices has a non-congruence subgroup with positive betti number, much less large. (see: http://www.worldscientific.com/doi/abs/10.1142/S0218196707004165 for a generalization, they don't have FA).

Comment: @IanAgol: thanks! They *do* have FA, btw. :)